# java reads "*" in args[0] as the .class file

Tags: java

I want some code in my program to run only if the user has input the character '*' at the command-line as a command-line argument. This is the code I've used:-

```
//myfile.java
import java.io.*;

public class myfile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args[0].equals("*")){          
            //do stuff
            System.out.println(args[0]);//added this line to see what exactly was being passed
        }
    }
}
```

When this program is executed at the command-line by entering:-

```
java myfile *
```

the output I'm expecting to see on the screen is the asterisk character, instead the output displayed is 'myfile.class'. Where am I going wrong? Why does Java change the asterisk to the .class file? 
Also, note that the program worked perfectly the first four times I executed it and then started doing this!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your shell does that: it expands * to all the files found in the current directory. Java has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Run your program like `java myfile '*'`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

> Where am I going wrong?

The star character needs to be quoted or escaped.  Run your java program like this:

```
java myfile "*"
```

or

```
java myfile \*
```

> Why does Java change the asterisk to the .class file?

It doesn't.  It is your shell that is doing it.  It is shell file expansion ... or "globbing" as it is also called.

Run "ls *" or "echo *" and you will see that the same thing happens.

Comment: Thank you! Using "*" worked. I'm using windows (command prompt) so the echo * and dir * don't seem to be affected by 'globbing'. But I definitely will look it up. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah yes.  On Windows, globbing is done ... inconsistently ... by applications rather than the shell.  (Another reason why Windows is not a good platform for programmers.)

Answer (score 1):

The command terminal already replaces the asterisk and java already gets the value that you see. I'd use any other character, that has no special meaning to the command terminal or otherwise you must escape the asterisk in your command.

Actually escaping arguments on Windows and especially in cmd.exe is non-trivial. This nice article explains it in detail: [Everyone quotes command line arguments the wrong way](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/) :
the takaway for your case is: surround the asterisk with quotes.

Answer to your question in the comment:

> Using the escape character worked! But I still don't get why it worked without the escape character the first few times

I am not sure, but maybe you run into this behavior: It makes a difference if the pattern can be expanded or not. For example, when I pass `Test*` as argument, then there are 2 cases to consider:

1. in the current folder there is a file called `Test1.txt`: then your java program will get `Test1.txt` as argument
2. when there are no matching files, your program will get `Test*` as argument

However, I am not sure, how this would apply to your case, since you only pass `*`: that should only work in an empty directory.

Comment: Thanks! Using the escape character worked! But I still don't get why it worked without the escape character the first few times... :-(